# Library for Android httpPost

Tags: android-studio

It's kinda frustating me... I tried to create httpPost 
code :

```js
private void makePostRequest() {


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // replace with your url
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("www.example.com");


        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test_user"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456789"));


        //Encoding POST data
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //making POST request.
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // write response to log
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But always ended Can't resolve symbol. I used Android Studio latest update, I already downloaded http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.5-bin.zip from hc.apache.org and copy jar file (httpclient-4.5.jar and httpcore-4.4.1.jar) to library and add it as a library but somehow it doesn't work.

It gives error :

> > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> >     Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES     File 1: Z:\Learning\Android-2\Live-code-AS\SendLocation\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.1.jar
> >       File 2:
> >     Z:\Learning\Android-2\Live-code-AS\SendLocation\app\libs\httpclient-4.5.jar

if I delete one of the jar file then I'll get "can't resolve HttpClient or NameValuePair"

Please help.... Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some duplicate files in your dependencies. To solve it, open your build.gradle in which you define your dependencies and add the packagingOptions-section within the android-section:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:(15, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
I got new error :
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Send Location' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: solved with packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
thanks.